# Including remote library with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've noticed that every time I want to use a package in Node I need to "npm install" it locally and then use the require keyword. I wanted to know if there's a way I could include a remote library kind of like that way we can include remote files using client side html when we use a CDN:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

`require()` in node core is synchronous, so there is no way to do it natively (since network i/o is async in node). You'd have to write some function to fetch the resource first and then `require()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually supply a URL to "require", but you can of course fetch a remote resource from a URL, including a javascript resource. And then load it locally.

The following answer even links to a "remote_require" that someone wrote to do another kludgy version of this.

[how to require from URL in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to use other JavaScript files in your application, you will need to export all of the functions defined by those JavaScript files.

You would export a function like so:

```
exports.nameOfExport = function(x, y, z) {
// Function content
};
```

You would then require this file in the file you are trying to use it in with this line:

```
var myFileName = require('./routes/folder1/myFileName'); // Relative path to required file
```

If this doesn't answer your question, I suggest going to https://www.npmjs.org/ to search for a package that does what you are trying to do.