# How to load Google Maps API in MeteorJS Server?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I am trying to load the Google Maps javascript API on the server side of my meteor app. I added two methods to `Meteor.methods` that use the google.maps but no matter how I try to load the api, I receive the error `Exception while invoking method 'getCoords' ReferenceError: google is not defined`. I understand that I cannot use the `<src>` tag to load the api, as I was using when I was prototyping with the API on the client side. I also tried using Iron Router with the waitOn library like so:

```
Router.map( function () {
this.route('codeEditor',{
  waitOn: function(){
      return [IRLibLoader.load('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry?key=MyKey')]
  }
 });
});
```

The relevant methods I have created are:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.methods({
    getCoords: function(startLocation,endLocation,priceFilter) {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var path = []
        var request = {
          origin:startLocation,
          destination:endLocation,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
          Meteor.call('samplePath',path);
        }
    });
```

If you have any insights, I would greatly appreciate them! Thank you!

Comment: what is `IRLibLoader`?

Comment: also, you are executing the `load` on the client, not the server, because the route you are defining is a client-side route, not a server route.

Comment: have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Comment: @ChristianFritz IRLibLoader is supposedly a way to load external JS scripts. It is included in the package `manuelschoebel:wait-on-lib`. I tried adding the `{where: 'server'}` option to the route, but that did not seem to solve the problem. It seems I have a lot to learn about iron router, but since this is supposed to be a single-page app, if I could find a way to load this JS without the package, I would prefer it.

Comment: @DrGorb Your link looks promising, but it appears in the supported api's page (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) that only the coordinates api and the maps-engine api are supported, which leads me to believe that I cannot have the full functionality I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remember that meteor is a framework based on node.js. The server side is node.js. So in order to load a library, your best bet is to look at how to load a library in node.js.

`require` does not allow you to load a remote file, but there seems to be ways around that. Have a look at this answer [how to require from URL in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js)