# How do I use an individual github file as a dependency in my package.json?

Tags: npm

I have an old project that uses this [project](https://github.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex) it is basically just a JS file. I have tried adding it a few ways...

```
"jquery-highlight-regex": "jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex"

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

"jquery-highlight-regex": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex/master/highlightRegex.js"
npm ERR! not a package /var/folders/vf/mnj9dq116gvcww95cbk3r3n40000gp/T/npm-32798-d819bc7b/raw.githubusercontent.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex/master/highlightRegex.js
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/.../bin/node" "/Users/.../apps/node/bin/npm" "install"
```

So how do I include a simple JS file as a dependency without a package.json?

Comment: More generally, when there's is no package available on NPM but I want to be able to download a single-file JS dependency as part of `npm install` rather than commit it to my repository, how can I do that?

Comment: Would a hook on postInstall or similar be about to download the additional file somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a postinstall script along with a dependency such as [`download-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-cli) to pull the file manually. This may be useful if the file changes often, as in *mjaggard*'s case.

The following example `package.json` will, upon install, fetch the file and place it in a `/third-party` folder.

```json
{
  "name": "so-npm-download-on-install",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "download --out third-party https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex/master/highlightRegex.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "download-cli": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

[Clone this example repo to try it out.](https://github.com/zbream/so-npm-download-on-install)

Answer (score 1):

As you've already discovered, you can't reference remote files by URL in your package.json, but you do have a few options here:

1. Commit the file to npm, either as a public or private package, then include it as a normal dependency.
2. Fetch the file dynamically then run it as suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810354/2972273) (this seems like a really poor option for a file that doesn't change).
3. Just copy the file and include it locally (not sure why you wouldn't do this since it doesn't seem like it's changed in 4+ years).

Comment: Option 1 might be a possibility for me, I'll investigate. Option 2 is a bad idea for quite a number of reasons. Option 3 might work for the original question author but not for me - my library gets updated quite regularly.