# Trying to import a javascript library that has no modules/packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to import a WebGL engine known as [PlayCanvas](https://github.com/playcanvas). It is very similar to three.js, but unlike `three.js`; it unfortunately does not have a npm package/bundle. Through the solution I got from this StackOverflow 
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877904/how-do-you-import-a-javascript-package-from-a-cdn-script-tag-in-react); I downloaded the engine code and imported it into my React Component.

The weird problem is that there is errors in the `playcanvas.min.js` I imported. I know for a fact that the engine code is correct, however the code relies on a physics engine called ammo.js and most of the `not defined` are as follows...

When I try to import the physics engine `ammo.js` into the playcanvas engine, my local host server crashes and refuses to render anything.

```js
Line 3:     'define' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 4:     'define' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 780:   'webkitAudioContext' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 880:   Unexpected use of 'self'             no-restricted-globals
  Line 1125:  'Ammo' is not defined                no-undef
  Line 1125:  'Ammo' is not defined                no-undef
  Line 1125:  'Ammo' is not defined                no-undef
  Line 1125:  'Ammo' is not defined                no-undef
```

I believe the main problem is that 
`<script src="https://code.playcanvas.com/playcanvas-latest.js"></script>` is very different from `import * as pc from './playcanvas.min.js'`

Comment: Out of interest, have you seen [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/playcanvas/engine/issues/932)?

Comment: Yes. I did have a look but did not pay much attention to it. Now I know you can install the whole engine because the contributors have created a `package.json` file.  I can now install it  by calling the github repo as such -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly). Is this the viable option? @SamHolmes Thanks.

Comment: It absolutely is!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a linter issue, try using [eslint-config-playcanvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-playcanvas) as a configuration rule. This seems to disable the warnings and errors related to PlayCanvas environment.

Here's [the instruction](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-a-shareable-configuration-package) on how to do it.