# how to fix eslint error 'pendo is not defined' in my react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to add pendo snippet in my react application I have included the javascript snippet and I use `pendo.initialize({visitor:{id:'id'})`
I validate using `pendo.validateInstall()`, all works fine but I've encountered a eslint error "pendo is not defined" in `pendo.initialize({visitor:{id:'id'})` which is used at my promise handler.

[My screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSakE.png)

Comment: ESLint tells you it's not defined because it *doesn't know about it*. It's not in the current file and I suspect it's some sort of global but without a visibility from the current location to the declaration *and* a thorough map of the dataflow of the application (which is beyond the scope of ESLint), it has no way of knowing that `pendo` will be declared and assigned a value by the time your code reaches the line with `pendo.initialize`.

Comment: Probably don't have the import of the module on top of the file. Most likely they have a proper js module so you don't have to use global variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877904/how-do-you-import-a-javascript-package-from-a-cdn-script-tag-in-react      I resolved that ESLint error using this thank you all for responding.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

`pendo.initialize({visitor:{id:'id'})`

use

`window.pendo.initialize({visitor:{id:'id'})`

Comment: This throws a typescript error : (

Answer (score 2):

You can add globals in the `eslint` configuration.

```json
"globals": {
    "pendo": true
}
```

If you want to override the error message just in one file, you add the following on top of your javascript file.

```
/* global pendo */
```

Checkout the eslint global [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals).

Answer (score 0):

You can install  "@types/pendo-io-browser" package with types for pendo.io https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pendo-io-browser

And add this type to your tsconfig.json:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "pendo-io-browser"
    ]
  }
```

After this just use pendo as any const without import. Works fine for me

```
pendo.initialize({})
```

Comment: Did not work for me.