# Variable is not defined, no-undef; How can I bypass this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react-create-app project that links a proprietary library in my public index.html that lets me use a variable called "SingularPlayer".

```
<script src="https://www.something.com/libs/singularplayer.js"></script>
```

for example I'm supposed to be able to:

```
const previewObj = SingularPlayer(iframeId);
```

But I can't because I keep getting this error:

> Line 67:  'SingularPlayer' is not defined  no-undef

I've tried putting these in my package.json but these didn't work either:

```
  "rules": {
    "no-undef": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "SingularPlayer": false
  },
  "env": {
    "SingularPlayer": true
  }
```

EDIT: my project won't let me run (npm start) until I fix the error unfortunately

Comment: If it's in the global namespace, try `window.SingularPlayer(iframeId)`. Or use `import` instead of a script tag.

Comment: i tried window.SingularPlayer in my old project where it works and it doesn't work for some reason.... i can't tell you why... once i remove the "window." and just put "SingularPlayer" it works.  I'll see if i can import the script

Comment: Try `"globals":{"SingularPlayer":"readonly"},` in the eslint config. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef#rule-details

Comment: try adding your code inside `window.onload = () => SingularPlayer(...)` it's probably because your script is running before SingularPlayer is loaded.

Comment: @HåkenLid that didn't work unfortunately but ty

Comment: @Kousha it's definitely not that, my project won't even let me npm start until i fix the error

Comment: What framework are you using? What exactly does `npm start` run?

Comment: @Kousha React using their recommended react-create-app to get started

Comment: If you are using `javascript` you should just be able to do `window.SinglarPlayer()` I just did that, and my app loaded, but then crashed because that does not exist.

Comment: @Kousha hm you may be right.  i will experiment thank you

Comment: If you are using TypeScript you have a few options. The easiest/cheat way is to `declare const window: any` at the top of the page, now you can do `window.SingularPlayer()`. Or create a `global.d.ts` file and then `interface Window { SingularPlayer: () => void }` or whatever the interface is

Comment: @Kousha using JS and JSX unfortunately

Comment: And using `window.SingularPlayer()` doesn't work? What's the error you get?

Comment: i'm thinking window.SingularPlayer() should work technically. it's the only way it makes sense.  I'm just figuring out why it's not working properly right now before I can say that at least

Comment: @HåkenLid window.SingularPlayer did work.  if you want to submit an Answer i'll give you credit.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the error by using below check,

(typeof fn === "function") - return true only if it's function

const previewObj = ((typeof SingularPlayer === "function") && SingularPlayer(iframeId));

To avoid compile error, recommending to download the script and refer from local

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.  Unfortunately my project won't even start regardless if putting that line of code in replacement as I get that error.. so my IDE won't even let me compile

Comment: no i haven't, but i'm not sure if that will fix the problem?

Comment: I would suggest to download and keep it in local rather than adding script link

Answer (score 0):

If 'SingularPlayer' isn't defined, it's not being included in the JS.

You'll need to import the singularplayer.js file in the JS files you want to access it from.

```
import SingularPlayer from '{url}/singularplayer.js'
```

You can't import a module from a URL in ES6, if you have to include the JS from another host, follow this questions answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877953/4953804

Comment: it says Module not found: Can't resolve 'https://..../singularplayer.js'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - global constant that was not accessible even through `window.ConstantName`.

I solved it thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2974#issuecomment-323403821) that guided me to create a new *proxy* file. The comment on the first line is the magic that solves the error.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const ConstantNameProxy = ConstantName;
export default ConstantNameProxy;
```

Then when I need to use the constant, I import and use the proxy such as:

```js
import ConstantNameProxy from './path/to/proxy/file';

console.log(ConstantNameProxy);
```

You could of course just add the comment before every line where you'd use the global constant or disable the error more globally on file level for example, but that'd be unnecessary amount of garbage around the real code and could hide other real errors.