# How to import javascript library from url and store it in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, import

**Background**

I usually code in python and am used to import libraries as follows:

```
import numpy as np
```

and then access the library as:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

However in javascript I can't get things to work this way. I am able to import a library through a url as follows:

```
<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/6726/8513/t/1/assets/hello.js?v=6940067293431132177" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
say_hi(); //say_hi is defined in hello.js
```

This works, but it is very confusing. I now have a bunch of functions that I can access directly but this pollutes my namespace. On top of that it isn't very clear from which library the functions are coming.

**Question**

Is there a way to access my 'hello' library through usage of an URL as follows:

```
hello.say_hi();
```

If so how do you do it?

**Research**

I know that you can use the 'export' and 'import' functions as follows

```
import * as hello from './hello.js';
```

with in hello.js an export defined as:

```
export {say_hi};
```

However I need to import it from a URL and I don't know how this would work with a URL.

I also found the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877904/how-do-you-import-a-javascript-package-from-a-cdn-script-tag-in-react) and thus tried:

```
<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/6726/8513/t/1/assets/hello.js?v=17694146303704268990"></script>
const hello = window.hello;
hello.say_hi()
```

But in this case hello is undefined...

I also tried out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/38817619) (answer of Rahul Srivastava):

```
var hello = document.createElement('script');
hello.setAttribute('src','//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/6726/8513/t/1/assets/hello.js?v=17694146303704268990');
document.head.appendChild(hello);
hello.say_hi();
```

But then again hello.say_hi() is not recognized.

*If this question is already answered elsewhere please do refer me, I can't find it.*

Comment: Your last snippet of code does work. `say_hi` is not defined in your script. `klotezooi` is defined however. You can then do, `window.test = klotezooi;`.

Comment: Sorry you're correct I took an old hello.js file. The correct one is in the post now. The last code snippet still doesn't work (hello.say_hi() is not a function). I also just tried say_hi() but that also didn't work and anyway it wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: Instead of `hello.say_hi();` in your last snippet, do `var hello = {'say_hi':window.say_hi};` then you can do `hello.say_hi();`

Comment: Still says the same: Uncaught TypeError: hello.say_hi is not a function. I tried it in shopify and on my local computer. FYI, just doing: window.say_hi(); also doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure the script is loaded correctly. Here's an example of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/ptLjezrv/

Comment: Thanks @JM-AGMS this does work. If you post this comment as an answer I will accept it, otherwise I can delete the question all together. Allthough I think it might help other people in the future.

Comment: PS: any idea why this didn't work? https://jsfiddle.net/AspyroCoder/tk6ogwfe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the script is loaded correctly. If you attach a script with JavaScript in the page, you will have to wait until it loaded before trying to call functions in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/t3gkyxf4/

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src','//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0561/6726/8513/t/1/assets/hello.js?v=17694146303704268990');
document.head.appendChild(script);
// waits until the page is fully loaded before calling or copying functions
window.onload = function() {
  var test = {
    'say_hi': window.say_hi
  };
  test.say_hi();
};
```