# Prevent libraries from being bundled and pull them from cdn instead

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, vite

I have a react app that I initiated with vite. I wanted to host the app on azure static web apps but apparently I'm exceeding the size limit which is 524288000 bytes.

The biggest contributors seem to be duckdb-wasm and fluentui so I'd like to not bundle those and just have the client get those from their respective CDNs.

Is that doable and if so, how would I do it?

For instance I have in my `App.tsx`

```
import * as duckdb from '@duckdb/duckdb-wasm';
import duckdb_wasm_eh from '@duckdb/duckdb-wasm/dist/duckdb-eh.wasm?url';
import eh_worker from '@duckdb/duckdb-wasm/dist/duckdb-browser-eh.worker.js?url';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { Stack, Text, initializeIcons, Pivot, PivotItem, Dropdown} from '@fluentui/react';
```

How would I replace those? Further, assuming it isn't the same answer, how do I tell the configuration to ignore them?

*Edit: this turned out to be a big [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I'll include my details in case it helps anyone else*

The issue was that in my yml file I needed to have `output_location` point to `./dist` since that's where vite build puts everything by default. Without that the azure or github action (not sure which) kept all the node_modules which were, of course, too big. With the output_location properly set it deployed just fine.

Comment: Does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877904/how-do-you-import-a-javascript-package-from-a-cdn-script-tag-in-react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load libraries from CDNs instead of bundling them in a Vite project:

1. **Add CDN Links in `index.html`**:

```html
<script src="CDN_LINK_FOR_DUCKDB"></script>
<script src="CDN_LINK_FOR_FLUENTUI"></script>
```

2. **Update Vite's Configuration (`vite.config.js`)**:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['@duckdb/duckdb-wasm', '@fluentui/react'],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['@duckdb/duckdb-wasm', '@fluentui/react']
  }
}
```

3. **Reference Global Variables in Your Code**:

```js
const DefaultButton = GLOBAL_VAR_FOR_FLUENTUI.DefaultButton;
```

Replace `CDN_LINK_FOR_DUCKDB`, `CDN_LINK_FOR_FLUENTUI`, and `GLOBAL_VAR_FOR_FLUENTUI` with the appropriate values.