# Including external JS script without the HTML script tag

Tags: javascript, unreal-engine4

Pardon my ignorance, as my knowledge of JS is very shallow.

I'm currently using [UnrealJS](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js-core) to connect to a Google Javascript API. UnrealJS basically runs a V8 instance inside the Unreal 4 engine. Considering that there's no conception of a DOM or HTML really inside UnrealJS, I need to be able to link to the external Google JS API script without the script tag:

```
<script src="some-external-script-url" />
```

Is there a way to do this? UnrealJS also supports Node.js - so if there's a way to do it with native Node.js, that would work as well. I'v looked into using require() from Node, but it seems to only be available for local scripts.

Apologies if this question is too vague or hard to understand, I will edit it if need be.

Comment: `import from ` might also work if you have a babel plugin.

Comment: Use npm install, and then require the modules - [see Install additional Node.js dependencies](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js/wiki/Running-the-examples#install-additional-nodejs-dependencies). You can add more deps to the package.json dependencies (it's in the scripts folder in the examples). After installing require the module you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with UnrealJS, but you've mentioned you can run Node code, and `require` modules. If that's the case, you can use an HTTP/S request to get the remote code, and then use `vm.runInThisContext` to inject the script into the current context. A sample code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js/7810354#7810354).